# The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release

Tags: react-native

I tried to update the react-native version to the latest from 0.59.8 to 0.60.3. But I got the following error when I try to run the app

```
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - native-base: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase#readme
  - react-native-code-push: https://microsoft.github.io/code-push
  - react-native-maps: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#readme
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - @react-native-community/async-storage (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/async-storage")
  - react-native-code-push (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-code-push")
  - react-native-geolocation-service (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-geolocation-service")
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-maps (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-maps")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
```

in react-native run-android Terminal, the error shows as below

```
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
  >   is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
```

I tried to update the dependencies. unlinked the dependencies and linked them again nothing helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove rnpm from package.json from native-base package. The file is located in `/node_modules/native-base/package.json`

follow this link

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/2749/commits/0bf3d4362116a17f9a4e311789a1a58dc6d98f37

Comment: why do I get this warning even though I am not using any rnpm?

Comment: and I dont have native-base in my node_modules

Answer (score 0):

To help the next one that has this problem.

Run the command below to remove the package with "rnpm":

**yarn remove react-native-update-gradle**

after the command below to update the dependencies:

**yarn upgrade**

worked for min.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `node-modules` and run `yarn`